# display weather forecast data from weather api in conky graph

Tags: jq, weather-api, conky

I would like my conky system monitor to show a time series of rain forecast probabilities as a graph. I request the forecast data via the darksky API and format it to csv with `jq` like this

```
curl "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/<myapikey>/<mylat>,<mylon>" | 
jq '.minutely.data | map([.time, .precipProbability] | join(",")) | join("\n") ' | 
sed 's/"//g' | sed 's/\\n/\n/g'
```

which produces output like this

```
1552253100,0
1552253160,0
1552253220,0
1552253280,0
1552253340,0
1552253400,0.01
1552253460,0.03
...
```

Is there a way to display this data in conky with `${execgraph ...}` or similar? As far as I understand, you can only pass a single value at a time to update `execgraph`, but I want to display an entire time series at once.

At the moment I pass the data to gnuplot, produce a graph and include it in conky as an `${image ...}` which works alright, but perhaps there is a native conky solution.

Answer (score 0):

If displaying the probabilities from when conky starts and thereafter is sufficient, you could use `${execgraph ...}` and just pass the latest value in the series each time conky updates.